# Pytorch Neural Network returns one value for the whole batch despite the input variables changing

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

My neural network only outputs one value across the entire batch even as the inputs change.
It is defined with two inputs - distance, x and time, t. The outputs are pressure, h and flowrate, q.

The neural network is physics informed so it solves the PDEs that govern fluid flow in a pipe for each iteration and includes this as part of the loss function. This is given as loss_pde and is defined in the training loop where F1 and F2 are the respective equations that include the PDEs.

As general testing and bug-fixing I have changed the activation function, optimiser and learning rate to try and fix the problem but it has no effect on the results

The neural network architecture is defined as:

```
class FCN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, N_INPUT, N_OUTPUT, N_HIDDEN, N_LAYERS):
    super().__init__()
    activation = nn.Tanh
    self.fcs = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(N_INPUT, N_HIDDEN),
        activation()
    )
    self.fch = nn.Sequential(*[
        nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(N_HIDDEN, N_HIDDEN),  # Adjust input size to N_HIDDEN
            activation()
        ) for _ in range(N_LAYERS - 1)
    ])
    self.fce = nn.Linear(N_HIDDEN, N_OUTPUT)  # Output layer

def forward(self, x, t):
    inputs = torch.cat([x, t], axis = 1)
    inputs = self.fcs(inputs)
    inputs = self.fch(inputs)
    outputs = self.fce(inputs)
    return outputs

pinn = FCN(2, 2, 9, 12)
```

The training loop is defined as:

```
for i in range (200001):

  w_f = 1e-3

  optimiser.zero_grad()

  colloc_output = pinn(x_colloc, t_colloc)

  h_hat, q_hat = colloc_output[:,0], colloc_output[:,1]

  dq_dt = torch.autograd.grad(q_hat, t_colloc, torch.ones_like(q_hat), create_graph=True)[0]
  dq_dx = torch.autograd.grad(q_hat, x_colloc, torch.ones_like(q_hat), create_graph=True)[0]
  dh_dt = torch.autograd.grad(h_hat, t_colloc, torch.ones_like(h_hat), create_graph=True)[0]
  dh_dx = torch.autograd.grad(h_hat, x_colloc, torch.ones_like(h_hat), create_graph=True)[0]

  F1 = Cs_A * dq_dt + q_hat * dq_dx + g * Cs_A**2 * dh_dx + f * (torch.abs(q_hat) * q_hat) / (2 * diam)
  F2 = Cs_A * dh_dt + q_hat * dh_dx + a**2/g * dq_dx

  loss_pde = torch.mean(F1**2 + F2**2)

  train_output = pinn(x_train_rand, t_train_rand)

  loss_data = torch.mean((train_output - hq_tr)**2)

  loss = w_f * loss_pde + loss_data 

  loss.backward()
  optimiser.step()
```

The results from this are shown as:
[image]

The inputs are a tensor of size (380,2) with each column representing x and t respectively. The x column is filled with one value = 155 m and the time column is filled with 380 values from 0, 10s. The grey line shows the expected behaviour of the system and the blue line shows the current output from the NN.
The data loss only reduces to a value of ~163 as this is the closest it can get to with only one value for the whole batch, the first 5 values are shown in the results above to demonstrate that all values are the same.

**UPDATE**:

I have now defined the inputs of the neural network as part of a dataset and then using a dataloader I have inputted the values into the neural network and the same problem occurs. The dataset and dataloader has been defined as follows

```
class TrainData(Dataset):
def __init__(self, x_traindata, t_traindata, h_train, q_train):
    train_input = torch.cat([x_traindata, t_traindata], axis = 1)
    train_aim = torch.cat([h_train, q_train], axis = 1)
    self.train_input = train_input
    self.train_aim = train_aim
    
def __len__(self):
    return self.train_input.size(0)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    input_value_x = self.train_input[idx, 0]
    input_value_t = self.train_input[idx, 1] 
    output_value_h = self.train_aim[idx, 0]
    output_value_q = self.train_aim[idx, 1]
    return input_value_x, input_value_t, output_value_h, output_value_q

class CollocData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x_colloc, t_colloc):
        colloc_input = torch.cat([x_colloc, t_colloc], axis = 1)
        self.colloc_input = colloc_input
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.colloc_input.size(0)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        input_x = self.colloc_input[idx, 0]
        input_t = self.colloc_input[idx, 1]
        return input_x, input_t
```

Where my inputs into the dataset are defined as:

```
x_train = torch.tensor(x_inp.values).to(dtype=torch.float32)
t_train = torch.tensor(t_inp.values).to(dtype=torch.float32)
h_train = torch.tensor(h_inp.values).to(dtype=torch.float32)
q_train = torch.tensor(q_inp.values).to(dtype=torch.float32)

x_colloc = torch.linspace(0, 300, 500).view(-1,1).requires_grad_(True)
t_colloc = torch.linspace(0, 10, 500).view(-1,1).requires_grad_(True)

test_dataset = TrainData(x_train, t_train, h_train, q_train)
colloc_dataset = CollocData(x_colloc, t_colloc)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size = x_train.size(0), shuffle=True)
colloc_dataloader = DataLoader(colloc_dataset, batch_size = x_colloc.size(0), shuffle = True)
```

The start of the training loop has been redefined as:

```
for i in range (200001):
for train_batch, colloc_batch in zip(train_dataloader, colloc_dataloader):

    optimiser.zero_grad()
    
    train_x, train_t, target_h, target_q = train_batch
    colloc_x, colloc_t = colloc_batch
        
    colloc_output = pinn(colloc_x.unsqueeze(1), colloc_t.unsqueeze(1))
        
    h_hat, q_hat = colloc_output[:,0], colloc_output[:,1]
```

These corrections should mean the data is inputted correctly thus the error must be from another section of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This part of code looks fine to me. I think the issue is that how you preprocess `x_collate` and `t_collate`. You should check whether they are identical for each batch in your experiment.

By the way, it's a convention to use `Dataset` and `Dataloader` to preprocess training data and wrap it to batches. See https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html#:~:text=class%20CustomImageDataset(,image%2C%20label and [https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html#:~:text=train_dataloader%20%3D%20DataLoader(training_data%2C%20batch_size%3D64%2C%20shuffle%3DTrue)](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html#:%7E:text=train_dataloader%20%3D%20DataLoader(training_data%2C%20batch_size%3D64%2C%20shuffle%3DTrue)) for examples. You don't need to read the whole tutorial.

Comment: I have edited the original question in response to your comment as the issue remains after using Dataset and Dataloader

Comment: @Felix Spiers Looks like the inputs of `pinn` are fine. But does this behavior happen after or before you train the model? If the model outputs the same value happens after the training, then that's what the model learns. It's very common for deep neural networks fails to learn the patterns of sequential signals if they don't change much over a many items, such as the ones in your image. You could try using infinite norm as loss function instead.